# Element-wise multiplication beween DataFrame and Series returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `time` Series and a `flag` DataFrame:

```
time
          0
action  -1.0
activ    1.0
actual   1.0

time.index
Index(['action', 'activ', 'actual'], dtype='object')

flag
        2000-05-10  2006-06-29
Entry                         
action    1.386294    1.386294
activ     0.000000    1.000000
actual    0.000000    0.000000

flag.index
Index(['action', 'activ', 'actual'], dtype='object', name='Entry')
```

I want to do the piece-wise multiplication between both:

```
flag.mul(time, axis=1)

        2000-05-10 00:00:00  2006-06-29 00:00:00   0
Entry                                               
action                  NaN                  NaN NaN
activ                   NaN                  NaN NaN
actual                  NaN                  NaN NaN
```

However, I was expecting this result:

```
        2000-05-10  2006-06-29
Entry                         
action   -1.386294   -1.386294
activ     0.000000    1.000000
actual    0.000000    0.000000
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to

```
flag.mul(time['0'], axis=0)
Out[286]: 
        2000-05-10  2006-06-29
Entry                         
action   -1.386294   -1.386294
activ     0.000000    1.000000
actual    0.000000    0.000000
```

Problem in your code , dataframe `mul` with dataframe , they should all have the same `index` and `columns` , in your case you should using `pd.Series`, also we should pick `axis=0`